# Control Cooler Master HAF X lights from Linux OS?

Tags: linux, desktop

I have a [Cooler Master HAF X Blue](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119239) and you can turn the fans on or off by opening up the case and clicking some buttons.

Is there any way to control these lights from within the operating system (assuming here that I am using Kubuntu 14.04 LTS). I would love it if I could write a script to turn the lights on if I am using the computer and turn them off if I am not.

Comment: Are the fan and lights connected separately? If not, this is probably not possible. Even if they are, It would probably be easier to attach a switch than to do it within the OS.